# Removing a header in GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, header, gnu

I'm trying to confirm or not if I am able to remove a header.

Let's say
I have a file data.gz:

```
This line is the header Data
Data line 1
Data line 2
Data line 3
Data line 4
Data line 5
```

I want to remove the first line before I do a regular expression

```
gunzip -c data.gz | grep -v '^This line is the header data$' | grep -o 'Data' | sort | uniq -c
```

Will this remove the header before I do second grep (regular expression) for data?  Is there a better method for removing a header in a pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! The `tail` command can skip lines counting from the beginning:

```
$ seq 1 3 | tail -n+2
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete first line with sed:

```
| sed 1d
```